# Slim 3 Routing not working

Tags: php, api, routes, slim

I'm trying to define a route to use a method in my class Users.

In index.php I have this:

```
$app->post('/user', '\Users:getUsers');
```

In dependencies.php I have:

```
$container['\Users'] = function ($container) {

 return new Users($container->get('ci'));

};
```

And in my class I have:

```
class Users {

protected $ci;
//Constructor
public function __construct(ContainerInterface $ci) {
   $this->ci = $ci;
}
public function getUsers(){

   $ci = $this->ci;
    $settings = require __DIR__ . '/../../src/settings.php';
    $user =  $app = new \Slim\App($settings);

            $userList =$this->db->table('tbl_test')->get();
            $output = array("data" => $userList);
            return json_encode($output);

   }
}
```

And the error I got is  **Class 'Users' not found**

Any idea why?

Comment: Where do you define `Users`?  How do you make it available to `index.php` and `dependencies.php`?

Comment: I tried with `require` but it gave me an error, because I was declaring twice. So I'm trying with `namespace`, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: like @geggleto said, definitely look into autoloading using Composer.  It will make your life a lot easier.  For bonus points, follow the [PSR-4 specs](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) for your classes and namespaces.  [This](http://phpenthusiast.com/blog/how-to-autoload-with-composer) is actually a pretty good tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial @alexw, I'll definitely look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Your users class is not defined anywhere in your project.
It likely comes from your usage in dependencies.php

It doesn't look like you are using autoloading... so make sure you are including a statement to include the class somewhere in your execution.

You should be using PSR-4 Namespaces for your classes.

Comment: I was importing it, but it gave me an error, because I was redeclaring it. So I tried Namespaces, which also didn't work.